# Foreign Keys for 4 tables in a GrandParent, Parent, Child, GrandChild so change the Parent Field cascades to GrandChild

Tags: sql, data-structures, sql-server-2016

I need to be able to change the `Chain_ID` in the parent table and have it cascade down to the assemblies table through use of foreign keys.

Currently there are foreign keys between the `Stores` and `Machines` which does work as when I change the `Chain_ID` in the `Store` table it does change the `Chain_ID` in the `Machines` table.

However the foreign key on the `Machine` and `Assemblies` tables does not update the `Assemblies` table `Chain_ID`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Database layout

```
USE [Test_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Chains]
(
    **[Chain_ID]** [INT] IDENTITY(1001,1) NOT NULL,
    [Chain_Name] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__ChainID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Chain_ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stores]
(
    **[Chain_ID]** [INT] NOT NULL,
    **[Store_ID]** [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Store_Name] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__ChainID_StoreID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Chain_ID] ASC, [Store_ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Machines]
(
    [Machine_ID] [INT] IDENTITY(10001,1) NOT NULL,
    **[Chain_ID]** [INT] NOT NULL,
    **[Store_ID]** [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [NVARCHAR](10) NULL,
    [Comments] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__MachineID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Machine_ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Machines] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__Machines_Stores] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([Chain_ID], [Store_ID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Stores] ([Chain_ID], [Store_ID])
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Machines] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__Machines_Stores]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assemblies]
(
    [Serial_Number] [NVARCHAR](11) NOT NULL,
    [Machine_ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    **[Chain_ID]** [INT] NOT NULL,
    **[Store_ID]** [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Equipment_Type] [NVARCHAR](42) NULL,
    [Status] [NVARCHAR](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__Serial_Number] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Serial_Number] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Assemblies]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__Assemblies_Machines] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Machine_ID])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Test_DB] ([Machine_ID])
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Assemblies] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__Assemblies_Machines]
GO
```

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, this is for SQL Server 2016

Comment: I think the current code have a mixup - the `Assemblies` table is referencing a table called `Test_DB` instead of `Machines`, and that reference only has `Machine_ID` in it.

Comment: Zohar - Thank you for pointing that out, I missed it when I was coming up with this example, but I still need help with the Foreign Keys

Comment: Well, if the foreign key doesn't include the `Chain_ID` column, why do you expect it to change as a result of a cascade update?

Comment: Zohar, I have tried several different relationships between the different tables and I finally hit a brick wall and ask the question with the last layout that I had tried hoping for an answer.  Maybe you could show me what is the correct way to set up the cascading relationships between the 4 Tables and what the Foreign Keys should look like.  That way I and others might learn from your knowledge.